# Embed Multiple DLL And Load Based Off Office Version

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, outlook

I am creating a windows form that from a button press event the user will send an email.  My issue is that some users have Outlook 2010, 2013 and 2016.  I know how to embed a dll into a windows form to be used when the windows form is distributed, however if I embed all 3 - however will I "assign" the proper Outlook.dll once the version has been detected?

**EDIT**
Or even better is there a 3rd party .dll that people have used that will allow you to interact with Outlook and generate an email and add attachments and save the email as a draft? -- Similar to how EPPlus will allow you to do "control" Excel and is totally independent of the Interop.Excel.dll

Comment: I think it's best to keep your questions as simple as possible. Reconsider to ask the first one first and the second one later.

Comment: @Stefan -> thank you for the words of wisdom.  I have edited my ? to only include one question

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the 2010 interop assemblies are incompatible with 2013 and 2016?  People often assume that they must build using assembly that matches the Office version, but as long as you do not attempt to use a _new_ feature in an older version, there will not be a problem.  The standard advise is to build against the oldest version and [embed the interop type information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342218(v=vs.100).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @TnTinMn -> I can try such but on my computer I have Outlook 2016 installed and when I go to add a reference I only have the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library Com reference. In order for me to start with the lowest version - 2010 - how would I get the Com eference?

Comment: You can [download the 2010 PIAs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) from MS.  I would use a Zip tool like 7Zip to just pull out the PIA CAB file from the "o2010pia.msi" file contained in "PiaRedist.exe".  These are stored in the "PIAREDIST.CAB" file. The "CAB" file will need to be expanded; from a command prompt, execute: `expand PIAREDIST.CAB -F:* .\2010PIAS`. Where "2010PIAS" is a folder you created in the same directory. You will need to reference the OUTLPIA.Dll and Office.Dll.

Comment: Also, you will probably need to alter how you create the Outlook instance.  Something like this: `Type outlookType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application");` then `Outlook.Application app = (Outlook.Application)System.Activator.CreateInstance(outlookType);`.